# Finding method of moments estimator, $EXP\sim(\beta,\mu)$

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution, method-of-moments

Assume $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a random sample of size $n$ with distribution $EXP\sim(\beta, \mu)$, find the method of moments estimator, $\tilde{\mu}_{mm}$ of $\mu$
I am confused as to what exactly I'm trying to find. So first I have:

$\mu_1=E[X]=\mu+\beta$

and then I have

$\mu_2=E[X^2]=VAR[X]+E[X]^2=\beta^2+(\mu+\beta)^2$

Which $\mu$ am i trying to isolate? Am I trying to isolate $\beta$ as well? I'm taking my first stats class and am very confused. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You haven't specified how these parameters enter the density or cdf. Presumably $\mu$ is a location-shift and $\beta$ a scale parameter in a two-parameter exponential; e.g. for the cdf do you mean $F_X(x) = 1 - \exp(-(x-\mu)/\beta)\,;\quad x>\mu;\:\mu,\,\beta>0$?

Comment: I do not know what you mean. My professor gave us three steps. Step 1: calculate low order moments, finding expressions for the moments in terms of the parameters. Step 2: Invert the expressions found in the previous step. Find new expressions for parameters in terms of the moments. Step 3: Insert the sample moments into the expressions obtained in the second step. I'm unsure of how to do this.

Comment: Let me be plainer about my previous comment: Define your distribution properly. Don't make people guess what you're working on. We are not mind readers."Exp" would normally refer to a one-parameter exponential (and most commonly indexed by a rate parameter rather than a scale, though I more often tend to the scale parameterization myself); While it's possible to guess at what you're doing, that process can become counfounded with any misunderstandings you may possess, making it harder to give answers that help you.

Comment: As for what you're unsure about, please show all your work up to the point where you can no longer progress and explain your difficulty. What stops you from following the instructions?

Comment: Without many concrete examples, the language used in the steps is what I find confusing. If I have not seen the process, I personally find the steps hard to understand. What I stated above was as far as I got. I had spent an hour pouring over my notes before I posed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to obtain an estimator for the $\mu$ that is on the RHS of your last two equations, by replacing $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ by their sample equivalents $m_1$ and $m_2$ and replacing $\mu$ and $\beta$ by symbols representing method of moments estimators (here I'll omit the "$_{mm}$" subscript and just use the "$\tilde{}$" over the top).

You will then have two equations in two unknowns; $\tilde{\mu}$ and $\tilde{\beta}$. A trivial manipulation/re-arrangement of the equations will give you explicit equations for both as a function of $m_1$ and $m_2$.

By the look of the question, you're specifically interested in $\tilde{\mu}$ but you'll essentially get $\tilde{\beta}$ along the way for free.